# SQLSTATE and GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS information in another function?

Tags: postgresql, function, exception, plpgsql

In one plpgsql function I have exception block like this:

```
exception when others then 
    txt := 'error text ';
    perform record_error(id, table, txt);
```

And when exception occurs I want to perform another function, which adds information about error to log table like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION record_error(
    id integer,
    layer text,
    message text)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$

            DECLARE 
               l_code  integer:= 'sqlstate' 
               l_mesg  varchar:= 'SQLERRM'; 
               l_context text;
               l_detail text;
            BEGIN

                GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS l_context = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;

                GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS l_detail = PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL;

               INSERT INTO error_log (            error_code ,
                                      error_message ,
                                      backtrace ,
                                      callstack ,
                                      created_on ,
                                      created_by ,
                                      user_msg ,
                                      etak_id ,
                                      layer )
                    VALUES (l_code ,
                            l_mesg ,
                            l_context, 
                            l_detail ,
                            current_timestamp  ,
                            CURRENT_USER ,
                            message ,
                            ETAK_ID ,
                            Layer );

            END;
            $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

But I get a message ERROR:  GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS cannot be used outside an exception handler.

Can I use SQLSTATE and GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS information in another function?

Comment: I think that's not possible. You must call `GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS` in the exception handler and pass the results to the error reporting function.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible. Reason for this limit is implementation of exceptions and exception handling in SQL functions. Because there is not sense to do it, it is prohibited by syntax.

Comment: Is there no way to avoid repeating the same boilerplate code in every function that needs to handle exceptions?  if, for example, you needed sql_state, constraint_name, table_name, column_name for a generic exception handling function, that's four variable declarations and one rather long 'get stacked diagnostics' statement in each function.

Comment: @HenryBigelow - I think so it is impossible.